# AsyncTask and socket not working in android java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm making a simple app client-server in java, i want my phone to receive and send messages to my pc, i'm on same LAN and my pc's ip is 192.168.1.8, my serverSocket is running on port 7777.
for some reason my client android cant connect i think it is because i created a socket in a thread, i have read that i should use AsyncTask or Handle, i tried with that too but i get an exception too.

Class server:

```
public class MyServer implements Runnable{


private ServerSocket server;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private Socket clientedConnected;

public ExampleServerZNuC(){
    try {
        server= new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("server opened on port 7777");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
public void sendMessage(String message){
    try {
        out.writeObject(message);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public void sendNotifiy(){
  try {
        out.writeObject("Send Notify");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
public String getMessage(){
  return "";
}
public void run(){
    System.out.println("method run started");
    System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect");
    try {
        Socket clientedConnected;
        clientedConnected = server.accept();
        System.out.println("A client connected : "+clientedConnected.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        in= new ObjectInputStream(clientedConnected.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientedConnected.getOutputStream());




                } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("End of method Run");
} }
```

this is the output i get when i create run the server:

```
 server opened on port 7777
 method run started
 Waiting for a client to connect
```

client android:
class to connect to my server( atm i just want it to receive the message):

```
 import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
  import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
  import java.io.OptionalDataException;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyConnect implements Runnable{

private Socket myconnect=null ;
private TextView txtMessage;
private ObjectInputStream in; 
private ObjectOutputStream out;
public MyConnect( ){
    try {
        // this is my pc's IP, my phone is connected to same LAN
        Log.d("inizializating socket","");
        myconnect= new Socket("192.168.1.8",7777);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(myconnect.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(myconnect.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d("My Error connecting",e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("My Error connecting",e.getMessage());
    }
 }
 @Override
 public void run() {
        try {
            String message = (String)in.readObject();
            Log.d("messaged recived",message);
        } catch (OptionalDataException e) {             
            Log.d("My Error connecting",e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Error My ClassNotFoundException",e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error My IOEXCEPTION",e.getMessage());
        }





  }

 }
```

this is the error that i get when i click on a button that should create the socket:
on create i use         connect= new MyConnect();
 and on onclick event i use:

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnExample:


        new Thread(connect).start();

        break;


    }

}
```

error message :

```
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):      android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at  libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
 05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):    at    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
05-29 19:02:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(6520):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
```

EDIT:

```
class MySyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>{
    String advice;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

    try {
        s = new Socket("192.168.1.8",7777);
        Log.d("socket connected","");
         ObjectInputStream streamReader = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 

            advice = (String)streamReader.readObject();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return "";
    }

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     txtMessage.setText("you got a message: " + advice);
}
protected void onPreExecute() {
   Log.d("my started","start");
}    

}
```

and i used

```
  MySyncTask asyncTask=new MySyncTask ();
     asyncTask.execute();
```

on onCreate() method but for some reason it is not connecting to my server

LogCat with AsyncTask:

```
05-29 19:46:21.900: D/my started(26169): start
05-29 19:46:22.020: D/libEGL(26169): loaded /system/lib/egl/l ibEGL_mali.so
05-29 19:46:22.030: D/libEGL(26169): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-29 19:46:22.040: D/libEGL(26169): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-29 19:46:22.080: D/OpenGLRenderer(26169): Enabling debug mode 0
```

**EDIT PROBLEM SOLVED**

after searching on internet why socket was not connecting i found someone who had a similar problem and i found the answer here [Android Socket not being instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337599/android-socket-not-being-instantiated?rq=1)
i had to initializate the socket first and then use connect

Comment: it is the same if i start the thread on onCreate() method

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are trying to perform a networking operation on the main thread. This is bad design, you do not want to lock up the user interface while you run a process that can take long time to execute.

Put your network method in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: i tried asyncTask that i read yesterday from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290387/android-socket-client-server but it is not connecting to my server now

Comment: what error are you getting ? If you can please paste stack trace again.

Comment: i'm not getting an error it is just not connecting because on my server i didnt get the output 
System.out.println("A client connected : "+clientedConnected.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()); it should print that when someone connects

Comment: If you have no errors than you will have exceptions. Return a string with e.getMessage() in every catch block so you can inspect it in onPostExecute.

Comment: i have done that now but anyway it is not showing any error, it is just not connecting

Comment: now i added    Log.d("socket connected1","");
 before s = new Socket and it doesnt prints "socket connected1" it is like if it is not executing the method doInBackGround

Answer (score 1):

Like Eduardo points out,

**[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)**

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.

Use [**Asynctask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your connection

Be sure to have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: edited now i tried with asynctask but it is not connecting to my server

Comment: ok thats another issue, be sure that you have connectivity to this ip "192.168.1.8" and port  "7777"

Comment: check your logCat and show us whats the exception, post in your question @Cosmicluck !

Comment: i did check my logCat and posted it here, i have not exception it must be a problem of logic with sockets

Comment: Be sure to have
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
into your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i added 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> too

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the proper permissions in the manifest? If yes, is the phone on the same network as your PC (if they are on same wifi network is good)? Try running through debugger and putting a break point.

Here is a nice tutorial that explains client/server communication in android.
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Good luck
-Raghu

Comment: @Raghu , I dont think networkonmainthreadexception can be thrown unless one doesnt have the permissions

Comment: and from what i understand i should use AsyncTask instead of Threads i had an error when i was using a Thread on client

Comment: I checked one of your comments and it appears the doInBackground is not even being called. Can you put a log message before you create the socket just to make sure that is the case? If yes, this may be just how you have defined the parameters. Instead of the first Integer, try Void as you are not passing any parameter.

Comment: i did, it is not being called but i called it onCreate()

Comment: this is how i used called it in OnCreate(): MySyncTask asyncTask=new MySyncTask ();
     asyncTask.execute();

Comment: I am puzzled. This could be just a parameter mismatch. If you are not passing any parameter, change it to Void. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942361/asynctask-what-parameters-are-needed-for-extending-and-doinbackground

Comment: changed to <Void, Void, String> and doInBackground(Void... arg0)  in onCreate() i use  MySyncTask asyncTask=new MySyncTask();
         asyncTask.execute();

Comment: Is this not working? Can you work backwards and put a log before even do the asyncTask.execute();?

Comment: it was not executing asyncTask but i solved the problem, i found someone who had a similar problem

Comment: Can you post how you solved the problem? It will be useful if anyone else runs into the same issue.